# Can we deduce that a finite topology $T$ satisfies Frankl's union-closed set conjecture?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $X$ be a finite set and $T$ be a topology on $X$. Then $T$ is both union-closed and intersection-closed. *Can we deduce that  $T$ satisfies [Frankl's union-closed set conjecture?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47419/difficult-examples-for-frankls-union-closed-conjecture)*

(We know that a complement of a union-closed set is an intersection-closed set and the union-closed set conjecture is equivalent to the intersection-closed set conjecture.)

Comment: How is this a set theory question?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Consider the minimal non-empty open set $A$. Each open set $B$ either contains $A$ (denote the family of such open sets by $P$) or does not intersect $A$ (the family of such open sets is denoted by $Q$). Then $B\rightarrow B\sqcup A$ is an injective map from $Q$ to $P$. Thus $|P|\geqslant |Q|$, i.e., at least half of open sets contain $A$.

Comment: Dear Fedor, many thanks for your nice and brief answer.