# Most important results in 2023

Tags: big-list

Last year I asked a question about the best [results in the year 2022](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435699/most-important-results-in-2022). This year I moved away from mathematics, but that does not eliminate my curiosity to know what great results were published, so what results do you consider to have been of great impact in this year 2023?

Comment: I repeat all the comments I made on last year's version of this question.

Comment: I have initiated a [discussion on meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5818) about whether this (type of) question is suitable for MO.

Comment: This question was temporarily deleted. During that time, it was [asked again by someone else](https://mathoverflow.net/q/461083).